# MySQL/SQL: I want to know the sorting criteria for Group by

Tags: mysql

I have a query such as:

```
select avg, day, unit_cd from table gropu by day;
```

result:

```
avg = 8, day = 2021/07/05, unit_cd = deg
```

When outputted by 'gropu by day',
What criteria result in one value even though there is data from different string values(ex deg, mm, cm, ...) in the unit_cd column?

Comment: *I have a query such as* This query is logically wrong. IIt is possible that a lot of diferent values for some column (for example, `unit_cd`) exists in a group with the same `day` - but one of them must be returned only. If so then it is unpredictable what value from all existing will be returned. Any column not listed in GROUP BY expression must be an argument of aggregate function.